# Docker: Installing mysql-devel - files are symlink instead of binary

Tags: docker, mysql2

I'm currently trying to deploy a Ruby application to AWS Lambda. When I build the container `docker build -t lambda-ruby2.5-mysqldep .` and I navigate to the `usr/lib64/mysql/` directory, the files are symlinks and  not the actual binaries. I tried using `unlink` and rebuilding but they still come up as symlinks. Why is that? is that correct?

```
bash-4.2# cd usr/lib64/mysql/
bash-4.2# ls
libmysqlclient_r.so  libmysqlclient.so  libmysqlclient.so.18  libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0  mysql_config  mysql_config55
bash-4.2# ls -l
total 2924
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Jun  4 18:16 libmysqlclient_r.so -> libmysqlclient.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Jun  4 18:16 libmysqlclient.so -> libmysqlclient.so.18
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      24 Jun  4 18:16 libmysqlclient.so.18 -> libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2983624 Dec  3  2018 libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    7035 Dec  3  2018 mysql_config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      12 Jun  4 18:16 mysql_config55 -> mysql_config
```

I think this is why I'm getting issues when testing the Lambda function. How can I reinstall and get the actual executable files instead of the symlinks? here is my Dockerfile

```
# Start with AWS lambda ruby environment
 FROM lambci/lambda:build-ruby2.5

 RUN yum -y install mysql-devel
 RUN gem update bundler

 WORKDIR /var/task

 CMD "/bin/bash"
```

Comment: That symlink structure is normal for Linux shared libraries.  All of them eventually point at the same concrete shared library file `libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Shouldn't these be the actual executable files?

Comment: I'm a little surprised the shared library file is executable, actually.  But there's nothing wrong with the symlinks here.  Is there a reason you expect something different, or a concrete problem you can demonstrate it causing?

Comment: @DavidMaze when I test the lambda_function I get the following error `/var/task/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/mysql2-0.5.2/lib/mysql2/client.rb:131: [BUG] 
`

Comment: @DavidMaze https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/1121